# How to delete thousands of records from sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have more than 5000-6000 records in SQLite table. When I delete this all records it takes very long time and causes screen pause and starts releasing resources.

I tried it with AsyncTask but still the same problem. So can anyone tell how should I delete this thousands of records without blocking app.

Comment: Have you tried truncate: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_delete.html

Comment: Try limiting your delete so that it deletes for example 10 rows at a time, and run it in a loop until you've deleted everything you want.

Comment: truncate can work also can you tell me about your db that why you do need delete 5000-6000 rows regulerly.

Comment: I tried truncate and delete table too. Truncate is fast but still not that much. I have one record in first table and in second table 5000+ records which are associated with first by foreign key. When I delete first one it deletes all related records from second table too but takes very large time and blocks app too.

Comment: Start a service and let handle it.

Comment: Do you have [proper indexes](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_indexes) on your tables?

Comment: You were probably doing it on `Main-Thread`. Long running tasks or I/O operations should be perform on worker thread! (P.S for any one else coming to this question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert to Sqlite but in general there are 3 ways to do that.

1. As every body commented Truncate if you are going to delete all record.
2. If you are going to majority of the records you can store the non-delete files in [tempTable](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html#tempdb) and then truncate your actual table finally insert all the records from temp to actual table
3. This one is what I use most of the time. Use a Top XXX delete statement in your case you can delete 200 records in every 2min. (I am assuming you don t insert more than 200 records in 2 min). The AsyncTask is the way for that kind of approach. 
   In T-SQL I use the following sql to it is up to you

   Delete From tUser
   where UserId in (
                    Select top 200 UserId 
                    From tUser 
                    where LastLoggin< GetDate()-120
   )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all records in a table you could try dropping the table:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html

and later re-creating an empty table:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Truncate is better the performing above two operations.

Comment: I tried drop, delete and truncate but not worked. All are slow to delete huge records which cause to pause screen.